Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]:Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exce with message: null
I am recently upgrading the Java 11 to Java 21 and Spring Boot 2.x to Spring boot 3.2.5. Post migration I am end up with a Run-time Exception which I do not have any clue at all.
I am using openrewrite recipe for migration.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception with message: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketTransportRegistration.addDecoratorFactory(WebSocketTransportRegistration.java:193) ~[spring-websocket-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at com.airbus.aclist.ws.WebSocketConfig.configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketConfig.java:42) ~[aco-aclist-commons-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.airbus.aclist.ws.WebSocketConfig.configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketConfig.java:74) ~[aco-aclist-commons-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]

My application is depend on another config service. I will include both the pom.xml for better understanding
pom.xml (for aclist-proxy)
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.airbus.aco.aclist</groupId>
    <artifactId>aclist-proxy</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <name>aclist</name>
    <description>AC list proxy project</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.19.0</log4j2.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.7.0</junit.jupiter.version>
        <powermock.version>2.0.9</powermock.version>
        <mockito-version>3.8.0</mockito-version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
        <argo.commons.version>1.2.4_GADLU</argo.commons.version>
        <!-- JaCoCo Properties -->
        <jacoco.version>0.8.6</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.33</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.airbus</groupId>
            <artifactId>argo-commons-feignclient</artifactId>
            <version>${argo.commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.airbus</groupId>
            <artifactId>argo-commons-security</artifactId>
            <version>${argo.commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.airbus</groupId>
            <artifactId>argo-commons-util</artifactId>
            <version>${argo.commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.32</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb-enhanced</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>autoscaling</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.airbus.aco.aclist</groupId>
      <artifactId>aco-aclist-commons</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

POM.xml for argo-common
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.airbus.aco.aclist</groupId>
  <artifactId>aco-aclist-commons</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>

  <name>aco-aclist-commons</name>
  <description>aco-aclist-commons</description>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <log4j2.version>2.19.0</log4j2.version>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.7.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    <powermock.version>2.0.9</powermock.version>
    <mockito-version>3.8.0</mockito-version>
    <!-- JaCoCo Properties -->
    <jacoco.version>0.8.9</jacoco.version>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.118</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.airbus.aco.aclist</groupId>
      <artifactId>aco-aclist-commons-models</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>dynamodb-enhanced</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
      <version>4.11.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

